# Firebase Dynamic Links not Available After Install

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I've implemented Firebase Dynamic Links and universal links are working as expected. For custom scheme URLs I get the call to `application:openURL:options:` but the link is never available. After I click on my Dynamic Link from the notes app, get taken to the App Store and launching my app from Xcode I always get `<my-scheme>://google/link/?dismiss=1&is_weak_match=1` which from what I've read it means that Firebase was successful in connecting to the server but couldn't find a pending link.

`DynamicLinks.performDiagnostics` has this output:

```
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start ----
Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 2.3.2
System information: OS iOS, OS version 11.2.6, model iPhone
Current date 2018-03-26 04:57:40 +0000
Device locale en-AU (raw en_AU), timezone Australia/Sydney
    Specified custom URL scheme is <my-scheme> and Info.plist contains such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.
    AppID Prefix: XXXXXXXXXX, Team ID: XXXXXXXXXX, AppId Prefix equal to Team ID: YES
performDiagnostic completed successfully! No errors found.
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output end ----
```

Configurations:

- Firebase `4.11.0`
- DynamicLinks `2.3.2`
- Xcode `9.2`
- Testing on an iPhone 7 Plus with iOS `11.2.6`.
- Tested on WiFi and Cellular

I've followed the documentation for setup and made sure that `FirebaseApp.configure()` is called on `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Any ideas of what I could be missing?

Comment: did you solve ?

Comment: It's a bug on Firebase side, I got it working at some point but it stopped working again. You can browse github issues on the iOS sdk and join the request to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase have a big problem with the dynamic link, the instruction is not really clear, base on :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains

and update this to your ios project:

```
// Info.plist
<dict>
  <key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
  <array>
    <string>https://yourtargetlink.com</string>
    <string>https://yourfirebasedynamiclink.com/link</string>
  </array>
</dict>
```

this will work for:
`https://yourfirebasedynamiclink.com/link/?link=${encodedLink}&apn=com.example&isi=1449448875&ibi=com.example`
`encodedLink=https://yourtargetlink.com` (you should encode it to this `https%3A%2F%2Fyourtargetlink.com`)